# Why does this firebase function run recursively?

Tags: node.js, firebase, recursion, google-cloud-functions

I'm guessing this is related to not understanding promises and execution order, but I'm currently stumped why this Firebase Function (repackaged Google Cloud Functions) code runs recursively.

Currently the function executes once successfully (fetches data, writes database entry, writes file in storage), and then repeats every 15-30 seconds until it reaches the '402' error state.  It is intended to only execute once.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
exports.add = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  cors(req, res, () => {
    if (req.query.idToken) {
      // there's a query param
      var idToken = req.query.idToken;

      admin.auth().verifyIdToken(idToken)
        .then(function(decodedToken) {
          var uid = decodedToken.uid;

          var userRef = database.ref('users/' + uid);
          var feedCountRef = database.ref('users/' + uid).child('feeds');
          var plansRef = database.ref('plans')

          userRef.once('value', function(snapshot){
            var feedsCount = snapshot.val().feeds;
            var currentPlan = snapshot.val().membership;
            var planRef = database.ref('plans/' + currentPlan);

            planRef.once('value', function(snapshot) {
              console.log(snapshot.val());
              var allowedFeeds = snapshot.val().feeds;
              if(feedsCount < allowedFeeds) {
                fetchFeed(req.body.feedSource, function(feedData) {
                  var defaultFeedName = 'Untitled';
                  var defaultUpdateFrequency = 'Weekly';

                  var feedsdatabaseRef = database.ref('feeds/' + uid);
                  var newFeedDatabaseRef = feedsdatabaseRef.push();
                  var feedKey = newFeedDatabaseRef.key;

                  writeFeedStorage(feedKey, feedData, function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    newFeedDatabaseRef.set({
                      // write data
                    })
                  });

                  feedCountRef.transaction(function(feeds){
                    return (feeds || 0) + 1;
                  });

                  return;
                });
              } else {
                console.log('over quota');
                res.status(402).send({error: 'You are at the maximum number of feeds your plan allows.'});
              }
            });
          })
        }).catch(function(error) {
          res.status(401);
        });
    } else {
      res.status(401);
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: What do you mean it "runs recursively"?  Could you be more specific about the behavior?  Logs?

Comment: @DougStevenson apologies. I meant the function continues to run repeatedly and has to be forcibly terminated. The answer was a missing "success response."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code snippet, a potential reason that it would be running repeatedly is that you are not returning an ok status if things worked out correctly, e.g.

`res.status(200).send('ok');`

According to the Firebase [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events#terminate_http_functions), this is something you should be doing for HTTP Functions.

Comment: Thank you, that fixed it! I can't believe I missed that.